# OPENCART - 4 products in category page

Tags: opencart

how can I put 4 products per line in my categories page
https://fixfone.pt/index.php?route=product/category&path=345

need help to resolve this :( 
I do not know what to do anymore

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to get free work.

Comment: Here you can ask some help by placing your code. We need to know what have you tried and maybe  if we find some errors in your code we will be able help you. Or put on the right way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just CSS. since you are using Bootstrap simply change the class for

`.product-grid.col-md-4`

to

`.product-grid.col-md-3`

if you catalog/view/theme/YOUR THEME/template/product/catalog.twig

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions. Please also see: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) as well as [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on default theme, just Go to this directory:

catalog/view/javascript/common.js (Line 164)

change:

`$('#product-list').attr('class', 'row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3');`

to

`$('#product-list').attr('class', 'row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-4');`

and go to (Line 177) and do the same change again then you are Done.